# Overfull in frametitle, reducing margin keeping the design

Tags: beamer, margins, warnings

If you run this simple code you get an overfull hbox. I think the reason is that the `beamercolorbox` in the title is `\paperwidth` large.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=.83cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to extend the title to the sidebar and avoid this overfull? What I would like to do is to move all text (normal text and text in the title) by .83cm keeping the background design fixed (for example setting the text margin do not work since it moves the `beamercolorbox` in the title).

Answer (score 1):

I would set the `text margin left` and then patch the `frametitle` template to also change the `leftskip` there:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.86cm}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperwidth,%
      sep=0pt,%
      leftskip=\dimexpr\moloch@frametitle@padding+0.86cm,%
      rightskip=\moloch@frametitle@padding,%
    ]{frametitle}%
  \moloch@frametitlestrut@start%
  \insertframetitle%
  \nolinebreak%
  \moloch@frametitlestrut@end%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]